# Shapley for Logistic regression?

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, logistic-regression, shap

Does shapley support logistic regression models?

Running the following code i get:

```
logmodel = LogisticRegression()
logmodel.fit(X_train,y_train)
predictions = logmodel.predict(X_test)
explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(logmodel )

Exception: Model type not yet supported by TreeExplainer: <class 'sklearn.linear_model.logistic.LogisticRegression'>
```

P.S. You are supposed to use a different explainder for different models

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Shap is model agnostic by definition. It looks like you have just chosen an explainer that doesn't suit your model type. I suggest looking at **KernelExplainer** which as described by the creators [here](https://github.com/slundberg/shap) is

> An implementation of Kernel SHAP, a model agnostic method to estimate SHAP values for any model. Because it makes not assumptions about the model type, KernelExplainer is slower than the other model type specific algorithms.

The documentation for Shap is mostly solid and has some decent examples.

Comment: Ah  i see. Thanks, this was simpler than i though, i appreciate it

Comment: No problem. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 4):

`explainer = shap.LinearExplainer(logmodel)` should work as Logistic Regression is a linear model.

Comment: It does, but only if there are two classes.

Answer (score 0):

Logistic Regression is a linear model, so you should use the linear explainer.